# How to intercept any UIApplication openURL calls?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7, wechat

I am using the [WeChat SDK](http://dev.wechat.com/wechatapi/documentation) to share some of my app's content to WeChat. From my observation, the sharing feature launches the WeChat app with [UIApplication](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html) `openURL`. A corner case that the WeChat developers did not handle was to show a warning when the WeChat app is not installed at all.  I want to handle this case myself by first checking `canOpenUrl` with the same URL passed into `openURL`. Unfortunately, I do not know the WeChat URL scheme because I only have their header and compiled files. Is there any way to intercept any `openURL` calls to figure out what URL is being opened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subclass `UIApplication` and have the app use your subclass. In your subclass, override `openURL:` and add your logic. When you're happy to continue with the open operation, call `[super openURL:...];`.

Teach the app to use your custom subclass by editing the main.m file:

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, NSStringFromClass([XXApplication class]), NSStringFromClass([XXAppDelegate class]));
```

*(Assuming `XXApplication` is your app subclass and `XXAppDelegate` is your app delegate class, and remembering to import the appropriate headers)*

Comment: It would help to point out how to setup the app/project to use the custom `UIApplication` subclass.

Comment: I got it. `- (BOOL)openURL:(NSURL *)url { NSLog(@"%@", url); return [super openURL:url];}`. The scheme is like this: *weixin://app/wxd930ea5d5a258f4f/sendreq/?*. Apparently "weixin" is the Chinese name for WeChat.